# WCF for creating documents from templates in SharePoint

Tags: wcf, sharepoint-2013, csom

I'd like to create a document in SharePoint 2013 using a call to a WCF (or any other web service) from my console application.

I've been told that WCF access is deprecated in SP13 and will be removed in future versions. Instead, CSOM is to be used (whatever that is).

My question is about the recommended approach. Is it smart to build a solution based on WCF connection (which I know very well how to do) or should I start reading up on the other approach?

Answer (score 0):

CSOM stands for Client-side Object Model. It comes in three flavors; .NET. JavaScript, and Silverlight. Using CSOM abstracts some of the plumbing that you have to do when using WCF directly but ultimately, CSOM talks to a WCF service called client.svc.

If you know WCF already, you can make RESTful calls using OData to that service from your app.

Here's more info about the different API's, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164060.aspx.

Here's more info about REST access: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164022.aspx.